# My Bottom Navigation Bar Only Works When I Double Tap To Switch Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I have created a Bottom Navigation Bar that switches between 4 fragments. It works fine, however, I need to double tap a menu item in order to switch between fragments. This is not a feature I want nor do I know how it even came about.

The tutorials I was following all require a single tap to switch between fragments so I am very confused.

My MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
     {
private FirebaseAuth auth;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if (auth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login_Page_Activity.class));
        }
        BottomNavigationView bottomnav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomnav.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(navListener); //this
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new explore_fragment()).commit();
    }

        private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener navListener=
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onNavigationItemReselected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                        case R.id.nav_explore:
                            selectedFragment = new explore_fragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_add:
                            selectedFragment = new add_events_fragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_events:
                            selectedFragment = new events_fragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_chat:
                            selectedFragment = new Chats_fragment();
                            break;
                    }
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            selectedFragment).commit();

                }
            };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the problem is Item ReselectedListener

try item selected listener

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
     {
private FirebaseAuth auth;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if (auth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login_Page_Activity.class));
        }
        BottomNavigationView bottomnav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomnav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener); //this
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new explore_fragment()).commit();
    }

        private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener=
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                    switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                        case R.id.nav_explore:
                            selectedFragment = new explore_fragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_add:
                            selectedFragment = new add_events_fragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_events:
                            selectedFragment = new events_fragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.nav_chat:
                            selectedFragment = new Chats_fragment();
                            break;
                    }
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            selectedFragment).commit();

                }
            };
```